# Slow modulation of the linear harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the classical harmonic oscillator:
$$
\ddot{q}+\omega^2q=0,
$$
which has a solution
$$
q(t)=a \cos (\omega t+\phi).
$$
Let me take $\phi=0$ for simplicity.
Suppose now that $\omega$, instead of being a  constant, is allowed to vary slowly with $t$, and that this functional relation is known. The fact that $\omega$ can change slowly with $t$ is modeled by introducing a slow time variable $T=\epsilon t$, with $\epsilon$ small.

The new equation of motion is:
$$
\ddot{q}+\omega^2(T)q=0.
$$
Consider the ansatz:
$$
q(t,T) = a(T) \cos(\omega(T)t).
$$
Clearly,
$$
\dot{q} = -a\omega\sin\omega t + \epsilon\left(a'\cos\omega t-a\omega't\sin\omega t\right),
$$
and
$$
\ddot{q} = -a\omega^2\cos\omega t - 2\epsilon\left(a\omega'\sin\omega t+a'\omega\sin\omega t + a\omega\omega't\cos\omega t\right) + \epsilon^2\left(a''\cos\omega t - 2a'\omega'\sin\omega t-a\omega'^2t^2\cos\omega t-a\omega'' t\sin\omega t\right),
$$
and replacing in the equation of motion gives:
$$
-2\epsilon\left(a\omega'\sin\omega t+ a'\omega\sin\omega t+ a\omega\omega' t\cos\omega t\right) + \epsilon^2\left(a''\cos\omega t-2a'\omega't\sin\omega t-a\omega'^2t^2\cos\omega t - a\omega'' t\sin\omega t\right) = 0.
$$
Note that the term $O(1)$ is identically zero.
I suppose that an equation for $a$ could be seeked by imposing that the term $O(\epsilon)$ vanishes as well. This would give:
$$
\frac{a'}{a} = -\frac{\omega'}{\omega}-\omega'\cot\omega t,
$$
which could be fine as $\omega$ is known, however the thing that puzzles me is that $a$ is a function of $T$, while on the right hand side there is a term which is a function of $t$. How to deal with this? Maybe my ansatz was wrong?

Comment: Didn't check your ansatz, but getting $a(t)$ sounds expected to me. The amplitude will in general change if the frequency is changing. Take $\omega = \omega_0 + \epsilon\omega_1$ and let $y_0$ be the solution for $\epsilon = 0$ then to first order in $\epsilon$ we have $y'' + \omega_0^2 y = -2\omega_0 \epsilon\omega_1 y \approx -2\omega_0\omega_1 \epsilon y_0 = F(t)$ so adding a time-varying frequency acts in a similar way as adding a driving force $F(t)$ to the oscillator.